# ballooneval in terminal vim

Tags: vim

I've been using [pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/) for debugging in `vim`. It works quite well on `gvim` with `ballooneval` to show the values of variables but the problem is I'm mostly using `vim` in a terminal so that I can't use the balloon feature.

I have found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_use/9Nw00bKITR0/5CkM4MYCWNcJ) but it looks abondoned already and I couldn't make it work as there's no installation instructions. Does anyone know a way to use `ballooneval` in terminal vim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From documentation:

> m  +balloon_eval        balloon-eval support. Included when compiling with
>                           supported GUI (Motif, GTK, GUI) and either
>                           Netbeans/Sun Workshop integration or +eval feature.

It's not quite clear though, whether this imply that terminal mode does not support `ballooneval` at all (or it's available in terminal mode when GUI is compiled in), but there's no clues to do that in the documentation.
So: it's highly unlikely that you can use `ballooneval` in the terminal mode without messing with the Vim sources.

Comment: that's what I guess but I was hoping there could be a plugin to redirect `balloonexpr` to a `preview window` or `autocomplete menu` (or whatever it's called).

Comment: @gokcehan I've looked into the Vim sources, the file implementing `+ballooneval` is called `src/gui_beval.c` and the balloon painting goes through gui_* functions.

Comment: well I guess than it's not possible to use native balloons in terminal vim. I will leave the question open in case someone comes up with an hack. you've got my +1 though, thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Vim version [8.0.1309](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/51b0f3701ecb440aa72ab6017c1df6940c0e0f6f) there is support for balloon in terminal. Seems to be work in progress though.

You can find a usage example in the following issue:

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2481